# Opening And Reading Large Numbers of Files in Python

Tags: python, file-io

I have 37 data files that I need to open and analyze using python. Rather than brute force my code with a lot of open() and close() statements, is there a concise way to open and read from a large number of files?

Comment: Use some sort of collection of file names/paths.

Comment: glob is useful to build your list of filenames

Comment: also `os.walk` can be useful here.

Comment: You can use wild cards on the command line and read the paths in sys.argv. `myscript.py *.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to open and close a file handle for each file you are hoping to read from. What is your aversion to doing it this way?

Are you looking for perhaps good way to determine which files need to be read?

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary of filenames to file handles and then iterate over the items. Or a list of tuples. Or two-dimensional arrays. Or or or ...

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard library [fileinput module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html)

Pass in the data files on the command line and process like this

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    process(line)
```

This iterates over all the lines of all the files passed in on the command line. This module also provides helper functions to let you know which file and line you are on currently.

Comment: I'm sure he has a better option then passing in all 37 file in the command line

Comment: @cmd, I am sure alternatives exist. Having said that, passing in a 40+ files to a command is not that uncommon a situation on UNIX-like systems. And there's always the `xargs` option for putting a list of files in a file to serve to a command.

Answer (score 0):

Use the arcane functionality known as a function.

```
def slurp(filename):
  """slurp will cleanly read in a file's contents, cleaning up after itself"""
  # Using the 'with' statement will automagically close 
  # the file handle when you're done.
  with open(filename, "r") as fh: 
    # if the files are too big to keep in-memory, then read by chunks 
    # instead and process the data into smaller data structures as needed.
    return fh.read()

data = [ slurp(filename) for filename in ["data1.dat", "data2.dat", "data3.dat"]]
```

You can also combine the entire thing:

```
for filename in ["a.dat", "b.dat", "c.dat"]:
  with open(filename,"r") as fh:
    for line in fh:
      process_line(line)
```

And so on...